# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {t}{{{\rm e}^{3\,\pi\,t}}-1}\ln \left( {t} ^{2}+{\frac{1}{4}} \right) }\,{\rm d}t$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, closed-form

I continue my work about the integral as $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {t\ln  \left( {t}^{2}+{z}^{2} \right) }{{
{\rm e}^{a\pi\,t}}-1}}\,{\rm d}t$.

Recently, i find the general formula for $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {t\ln  \left( {t}^{2}+{z}^{2} \right) }{{
{\rm e}^{3\,\pi\,t}}-1}}\,{\rm d}t$ in terms of Barnes G-function

And for example i have $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {t}{{{\rm e}^{3\,\pi\,t}}-1}\ln\left( {t}
^{2}+{\frac{1}{4}} \right) }\,{\rm d}t$ = $-{\frac {\ln  \left( \pi \right) }{6}}-{\frac {23\,\ln  \left( 2
 \right) }{108}}-{\frac {{\it G}}{9\,\pi}}-{\frac{83}{432}}+{
\frac {\ln  \left( A \right) }{18}}+{\frac {19\,\ln  \left( 3 \right) 
}{216}}+{\frac {\ln  \left( \Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right) 
 \right) }{3}}$ where G is the Catalan's  constant and A is the Glaisher-Kinkelin's constant.

But i don't have any idea if we can prove this closed form with the residue theorem.

Please if someone can prove it ?